# Can 2 different versions of MySQL be run side by side?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, debian

I have Debian 10 installed and have an instance of MySQL 8 running.

I'd like to install 5.7 to try and bring up the database of a machine that failed, where I have the data directory fully intact, so I can inspect it and save the schemas, data, triggers, functions and stored procedures.

Does this question make sense?

Comment: The answer to both of your questions is "yes".

Comment: lol. Ok. Great.

Comment: Now if you were to ask _how_ to install a different version of MySQL on a server running MySQL 8, that would be a more interesting and useful question. In that case I'd suggest running it as a Docker container.

Comment: Oh hey! THat's a great idea. My machine is a new Acer 6 core machine. That actually sounds perfect. I'm glad you thought of it.

Comment: If / when you share your experience setting it up, as the answer to this question, I'll happily upvote it.

Comment: Also a good idea. Will do that once it's done.

Comment: I have the docker set up, now I'm trying to figure out how to get the docker instance to use my backup data directory.

Comment: `-v /your/local/dir:/var/lib/mysql:Z`?

Comment: Yes. I figured it out. working on creating proper dumps of the now restored database.

Answer (score 2):

The database I wanted to restore was actually MySQL 5.5.29. OH NO!
Based on the suggestion of [@mustaccio](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/23721/mustaccio), I set up a docker container to
run the MySQL 5.5 instance.

[bazzani](https://github.com/bazzani/mysql-5.5-docker) has a MySQL 5.5 docker image builder so I used that
The last step, to use the backed up MySQl instance files with the docker image
was completed with:

```
docker run --name=mysql55 -d -v ~/mysql:/var/lib/mysql mysql5.5
```

Find the IPAddress of MySQL in the container:

```
docker inspect mysql55 | grep -i ipaddress
```

After that it was easy to access the database and properly dump the data, schema and triggers and grants:

1. Grants

   `mysql -u user -ppassword --skip-column-names -A -e"SELECT CONCAT('SHOW GRANTS FOR ',QUOTE(user),'@',QUOTE(host),';') FROM mysql.user WHERE user<>''" | mysql -u user -ppassword --skip-column-names -A | sed 's/$/;/g' > MySQLUserGrants.sql`
2. Routines

   `mysqldump --column-statistics=0 -h 172.17.0.2 -u user -ppassword  --no-data --no-create-info --routines ${DB} > ${DB}-routines.sql`
3. Schema and Triggers

   `mysqldump --column-statistics=0 -h 172.17.0.2 -u user -ppassword --no-data --triggers ${DB} > ${DB}-schema-triggers.sql`
4. Data

   `mysqldump --column-statistics=0 -h 172.17.0.2 -u user -ppassword --no-create-info --skip-triggers --no-create-db --compact ${DB} > ${DB}-data-only.sql`

This whole solution was important as 12 months of research in multiple databases had been poorly backed up using mysqldump this way:

```
mysqldump --force --opt --user=$MYSQL_USER -p$MYSQL_PASSWORD --databases $db
```

This command dumps everything in a single file, which is not workable, so all current backups mostly useless. Fortunately the old drive is solid though the machine is dead.